# How can i grab text from a web browser?

Tags: vb.net

I need to go into my implemented web browser and take text from lets say a label on the page. For example on this page it says "Related Questions" I need to copy that text and paste it into my from. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're using a WebBrowser element to show a homepage on your form. Use the following short code snippet to get the source code of the website you're viewing (the source code will be written into the `TextBox1` in that example). Now you'll just have to filter out whatever you need (in your case it's a certain text which is hopefully between two HTML elements for ease). You might need RegEx for that (in case you're looking for an easy solution).

```
TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentText
```